# Here Maps Routing Api returning 404 1 out of 5 times

Tags: here-api

I've integrated Here maps JS into a website, and when I call the "calculateRoute" method like so: `router.calculateRoute(routingParameters, onRoutingResult)`, this makes a call to the following URL which returns a 404 most of the time.

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.9.0&apikey=my-api-key&mode=fastest%3Bcar&waypoint0=geo!-33.873367%2C151.247373&waypoint1=geo!-33.873392%2C151.224161&routeAttributes=sh

When it works, it returns the JSON structure as expected

Is this a temporary issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The URL is working for me (but it wants an API key, which I don't have). Sounds like a good question to ask the website's owner.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the feedback. we have forwarded this request to our development  team for further investigation.

Comment: We're having the same issue, but just wanted to point out it looks like this isn't currently working even in the examples on HERE's documentation website. https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/map-with-route-from-a-to-b is attempting to do the same thing and getting the same error.

Comment: @here-developer-support is there any update here?

Comment: @Jason Wiener Team is working on it.

Comment: @dwatland https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/map-with-route-from-a-to-b this example is working as expected. please check again.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport we're still getting the same error as described above both on the example you linked and when we're trying to use the endpoint in our application.

Comment: @dwatland This seems to be working for me now, though a bit slow. Any updates on your end?

Comment: seems like the examples in the documentation are obsolet, after checking against the examples it workes for me: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/routing

Answer (score 0):

for all having problems with the examples from the "quick start" doc, check your URL against these:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/routing